# Error while wrting data into file using Applescript

Tags: applescript

am using the below script for writing the file, but sometimes am getting errors like mentioned below, pls suggest..

```
set filepath to POSIX path of "Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Macromedia:mms.cfg"
try
    tell application "System Events"
        if file filepath exists then
            set myFile to open for access file filepath with write permission
            set fileData to read myFile
            set eof myFile to 0
            write "blah blah" to myFile
            close access myFile
        else
            return "File Not Found"
        end if
    end tell
on error
    return false
end try
```

Error:

```
 "Network file permission error." number -5000 from file "Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Macromedia:mms.cfg"
```

Also some times i will get this error, am unable to close the opened file

```
"File file Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Macromedia:mms.cfg is already open." number -49 from file "Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Macromedia:mms.cfg"
```

When i tried to close the ofile am getting this eror:

```
on openAFile(filepath)
    try
        set fp to open for access filepath with write permission

    on error errstr number errNum
        if errNum = -49 then
            close access filepath
            set fp to open for access filepath with write permission
        else
            display dialog errstr
            return false
        end if
    end try

    return fp
end openAFile

set pointer to openAFile("Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Macromedia:mms.cfg"
set fileContents to read pointer
```

Error

```
"Can’t make \"Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Macromedia:mms.cfg\" into type file." number -1700 from "Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Macromedia:mms.cfg" to file
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the "Network file permission error" that you are receiving.

The "File file Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Macromedia:mms.cfg is already open." error happens when you script stops in the Script Editor without closing the file.  This happens if there is some other logic error that prevents AppleScript from reaching the `close access` command in your `on error` block (or you press the Stop button at an inopportune time).  Apple's AppleScript Editor does not close leaked file references for you when a script stops.

Your workaround of trying to close the file before opening it may work, but you are passing a string rather than a `file` or `alias` for the filepath.  Use `open for access file filepath` and `close access file filepath`.

Comment: is their any way to solve the Network file permission error??